# Flutter Android Studio does not show all "wrap with" (intentions) options

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Whenever I try to use the "wrap with" option on a widget (Alt + Enter on windows / Option + Enter on macOS), I'm getting a limited list of available wrap widgets that I can use (all of them related to the flutter_bloc package).

[image]

I'm looking to get the full default flutter list like this:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem Solved!

All I had to do is to:

1. Go to **Preferences -> Editor -> Intentions**
2. Then search for "Dart"
3. Enable the **"Quick assists powered by Dart Analysis"**

IDK why it went down. But raising this again solved my issue.

Comment: Easier way : Go to settings -> Search for it : https://i.imgur.com/c1x4M8h.png

Answer (score 4):

I tried following the other answer but I already had that flag checked; also, I didn't find **Preferences**, I had to go to **Settings -> Editor -> Intentions**.

I am very new to flutter so it may be obvious for some but I resolved by removing the **const** keyword.

**Before**:

[image]

**After**:

[image]

Comment: -> then search for "Dart"
-> "Enable the "Quick assists powered by Dart Analysis"